# How can I send both text and image?

Tags: python, image, sockets, networking

In my chat application, only the text is can be sent right now. I'm trying to add a feature in which the images can also be sent. However, there is one point I'm stuck in. When receiving the data, how can I discriminate between photo and text? I'm asking this because these two are completely different procedures. In one of them, we encode it with UTF-8 and send, while in the other we send bytes. On the server side, how can I discriminate them?

I was able to add a send-photo feature on the client side as shown below. When I try it, it succesfully sends image bytes. The only thing I need to is to discriminate the text from bytes on the server side.

As my code is too long, I prefer not to add all of it here. You can access it through my github https://github.com/suleymanyaman/randomchatserver

Client

```
def sendphoto():
 dlg = QFileDialog()
 dlg.setFileMode(QFileDialog.AnyFile)
 img_dir = QStringListModel()

 if dlg.exec_():
     img_dir = dlg.selectedFiles()[0]
     data = open(r'{}'.format(img_dir),'rb').read()
     s.send(data)
```

Server

```
    while 1:
      msg = client.recv(100000000).decode("utf-8")
```

Answer (score 0):

Once it's on the network, everything is bytes.  To add support for images, you just need to send some message that says "An image is coming next."  Your protocol hopefully already has some "control messages" that you can use for this.

If you want to keep the protocol "readable" (i.e. you prefer all bytes to be sensible UTF-8), you could use base 64 encoding or similar to turn your images into "text" before sending them.  But that probably isn't necessary.